# installing bcrypt using npm failes with error code 7

Tags: node.js, npm

This question raised a lot, still haven't found what I'm looking for.

Using:

- Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- npm version 10.1.0
- node version 18.18.0

Trying and failing (also with sudo):
`npm install bcrypt`

```
0 verbose cli /snap/node/7823/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
1 info using npm@10.1.0
2 info using node@v18.18.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 15ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 0ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 0ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/home/roee/Projects/Xxx/Xxx-Systems-Website/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
11 timing config:load:file:/home/roee/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:/snap/node/7823/etc/npmrc Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 5ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 5ms
18 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 2ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
21 verbose title npm install bcrypt
22 verbose argv "install" "bcrypt"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 0ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/home/roee/.npm/_logs/2023-09-24T22_34_06_584Z-
26 verbose logfile /home/roee/.npm/_logs/2023-09-24T22_34_06_584Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 11ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 47ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
32 silly logfile done cleaning log files
33 timing idealTree:init Completed in 40ms
34 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 1ms
35 silly idealTree buildDeps
36 silly fetch manifest bcrypt@*
37 verbose shrinkwrap failed to load node_modules/.package-lock.json out of date, updated: node_modules
38 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt 40ms (cache hit)
39 silly placeDep ROOT bcrypt@5.1.1 OK for: gullivware-systems-website@1.0.0 want: *
40 silly fetch manifest @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@^1.0.11
41 silly fetch manifest node-addon-api@^5.0.0
42 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@mapbox%2fnode-pre-gyp 8ms (cache hit)
43 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-addon-api 9ms (cache hit)
44 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 57ms
45 silly placeDep ROOT @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.11 OK for: bcrypt@5.1.1 want: ^1.0.11
46 silly fetch manifest detect-libc@^2.0.0
47 silly fetch manifest https-proxy-agent@^5.0.0
48 silly fetch manifest make-dir@^3.1.0
49 silly fetch manifest node-fetch@^2.6.7
50 silly fetch manifest nopt@^5.0.0
51 silly fetch manifest npmlog@^5.0.1
52 silly fetch manifest rimraf@^3.0.2
53 silly fetch manifest semver@^7.3.5
54 silly fetch manifest tar@^6.1.11
55 silly placeDep ROOT node-addon-api@5.1.0 OK for: bcrypt@5.1.1 want: ^5.0.0
56 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/detect-libc 20ms (cache hit)
57 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/https-proxy-agent 20ms (cache hit)
58 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/make-dir 21ms (cache hit)
59 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-fetch 22ms (cache hit)
60 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt 25ms (cache hit)
61 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npmlog 25ms (cache hit)
62 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf 25ms (cache hit)
63 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver 27ms (cache hit)
64 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar 32ms (cache hit)
65 timing idealTree:node_modules/bcrypt Completed in 37ms
66 silly fetch manifest encoding@^0.1.0
67 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/encoding 5ms (cache hit)
68 silly placeDep ROOT detect-libc@2.0.2 OK for: @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.11 want: ^2.0.0
69 silly placeDep ROOT https-proxy-agent@5.0.1 OK for: @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.11 want: ^5.0.0
70 silly fetch manifest agent-base@6
71 silly fetch manifest debug@4
72 silly placeDep ROOT make-dir@3.1.0 OK for: @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.11 want: ^3.1.0
73 silly fetch manifest semver@^6.0.0
74 silly placeDep ROOT node-fetch@2.7.0 OK for: @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.11 want: ^2.6.7
75 silly fetch manifest whatwg-url@^5.0.0
76 silly placeDep ROOT nopt@5.0.0 OK for: @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.11 want: ^5.0.0
77 silly fetch manifest abbrev@1
78 silly placeDep ROOT npmlog@5.0.1 OK for: @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.11 want: ^5.0.1
79 silly fetch manifest are-we-there-yet@^2.0.0
80 silly fetch manifest console-control-strings@^1.1.0
81 silly fetch manifest gauge@^3.0.0
82 silly fetch manifest set-blocking@^2.0.0
83 silly placeDep ROOT rimraf@3.0.2 OK for: @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.11 want: ^3.0.2
84 silly fetch manifest glob@^7.1.3
85 silly placeDep ROOT semver@7.5.4 OK for: @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.11 want: ^7.3.5
86 silly fetch manifest lru-cache@^6.0.0
87 silly placeDep ROOT tar@6.2.0 OK for: @mapbox/node-pre-gyp@1.0.11 want: ^6.1.11
88 silly fetch manifest chownr@^2.0.0
89 silly fetch manifest fs-minipass@^2.0.0
90 silly fetch manifest minipass@^5.0.0
91 silly fetch manifest minizlib@^2.1.1
92 silly fetch manifest mkdirp@^1.0.3
93 silly fetch manifest yallist@^4.0.0
94 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/agent-base 45ms (cache hit)
95 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug 45ms (cache hit)
96 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/whatwg-url 39ms (cache hit)
97 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev 39ms (cache hit)
98 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/are-we-there-yet 39ms (cache hit)
99 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/console-control-strings 44ms (cache hit)
100 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/gauge 43ms (cache hit)
101 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/set-blocking 44ms (cache hit)
102 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob 41ms (cache hit)
103 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache 42ms (cache hit)
104 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/chownr 50ms (cache hit)
105 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-minipass 50ms (cache hit)
106 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minipass 51ms (cache hit)
107 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minizlib 51ms (cache hit)
108 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp 51ms (cache hit)
109 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yallist 52ms (cache hit)
110 timing idealTree:node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp Completed in 77ms
111 timing idealTree:node_modules/detect-libc Completed in 0ms
112 silly placeDep ROOT agent-base@6.0.2 OK for: https-proxy-agent@5.0.1 want: 6
113 silly placeDep node_modules/https-proxy-agent debug@4.3.4 OK for: https-proxy-agent@5.0.1 want: 4
114 silly fetch manifest ms@2.1.2
115 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms 9ms (cache hit)
116 timing idealTree:node_modules/https-proxy-agent Completed in 15ms
117 silly placeDep node_modules/agent-base debug@4.3.4 OK for: agent-base@6.0.2 want: 4
118 timing idealTree:node_modules/agent-base Completed in 2ms
119 silly placeDep node_modules/make-dir semver@6.3.1 OK for: make-dir@3.1.0 want: ^6.0.0
120 timing idealTree:node_modules/make-dir Completed in 3ms
121 timing idealTree:node_modules/node-addon-api Completed in 0ms
122 silly placeDep ROOT whatwg-url@5.0.0 OK for: node-fetch@2.7.0 want: ^5.0.0
123 silly fetch manifest tr46@~0.0.3
124 silly fetch manifest webidl-conversions@^3.0.0
125 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/tr46 12ms (cache hit)
126 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/webidl-conversions 12ms (cache hit)
127 timing idealTree:node_modules/node-fetch Completed in 14ms
128 silly placeDep ROOT abbrev@1.1.1 OK for: nopt@5.0.0 want: 1
129 timing idealTree:node_modules/nopt Completed in 0ms
130 timing idealTree:node_modules/abbrev Completed in 0ms
131 silly placeDep ROOT are-we-there-yet@2.0.0 OK for: npmlog@5.0.1 want: ^2.0.0
132 silly fetch manifest delegates@^1.0.0
133 silly fetch manifest readable-stream@^3.6.0
134 silly placeDep ROOT console-control-strings@1.1.0 OK for: npmlog@5.0.1 want: ^1.1.0
135 silly placeDep ROOT gauge@3.0.2 OK for: npmlog@5.0.1 want: ^3.0.0
136 silly fetch manifest aproba@^1.0.3 || ^2.0.0
137 silly fetch manifest color-support@^1.1.2
138 silly fetch manifest has-unicode@^2.0.1
139 silly fetch manifest object-assign@^4.1.1
140 silly fetch manifest signal-exit@^3.0.0
141 silly fetch manifest string-width@^4.2.3
142 silly fetch manifest strip-ansi@^6.0.1
143 silly fetch manifest wide-align@^1.1.2
144 silly placeDep ROOT set-blocking@2.0.0 OK for: npmlog@5.0.1 want: ^2.0.0
145 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/delegates 40ms (cache hit)
146 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream 40ms (cache hit)
147 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/aproba 37ms (cache hit)
148 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/color-support 36ms (cache hit)
149 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-unicode 35ms (cache hit)
150 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/object-assign 35ms (cache hit)
151 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/signal-exit 34ms (cache hit)
152 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/string-width 39ms (cache hit)
153 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi 37ms (cache hit)
154 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/wide-align 39ms (cache hit)
155 timing idealTree:node_modules/npmlog Completed in 58ms
156 silly placeDep ROOT delegates@1.0.0 OK for: are-we-there-yet@2.0.0 want: ^1.0.0
157 silly placeDep ROOT readable-stream@3.6.2 OK for: are-we-there-yet@2.0.0 want: ^3.6.0
158 silly fetch manifest string_decoder@^1.1.1
159 silly fetch manifest util-deprecate@^1.0.1
160 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder 6ms (cache hit)
161 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/util-deprecate 5ms (cache hit)
162 timing idealTree:node_modules/are-we-there-yet Completed in 7ms
163 timing idealTree:node_modules/console-control-strings Completed in 0ms
164 timing idealTree:node_modules/delegates Completed in 0ms
165 silly placeDep ROOT aproba@2.0.0 OK for: gauge@3.0.2 want: ^1.0.3 || ^2.0.0
166 silly placeDep ROOT color-support@1.1.3 OK for: gauge@3.0.2 want: ^1.1.2
167 silly placeDep ROOT has-unicode@2.0.1 OK for: gauge@3.0.2 want: ^2.0.1
168 silly placeDep ROOT object-assign@4.1.1 OK for: gauge@3.0.2 want: ^4.1.1
169 silly placeDep ROOT signal-exit@3.0.7 OK for: gauge@3.0.2 want: ^3.0.0
170 silly placeDep ROOT string-width@4.2.3 OK for: gauge@3.0.2 want: ^4.2.3
171 silly fetch manifest emoji-regex@^8.0.0
172 silly fetch manifest is-fullwidth-code-point@^3.0.0
173 silly placeDep ROOT strip-ansi@6.0.1 OK for: gauge@3.0.2 want: ^6.0.1
174 silly fetch manifest ansi-regex@^5.0.1
175 silly placeDep ROOT wide-align@1.1.5 OK for: gauge@3.0.2 want: ^1.1.2
176 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/emoji-regex 11ms (cache hit)
177 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-fullwidth-code-point 11ms (cache hit)
178 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex 10ms (cache hit)
179 timing idealTree:node_modules/gauge Completed in 25ms
180 timing idealTree:node_modules/aproba Completed in 0ms
181 timing idealTree:node_modules/color-support Completed in 0ms
182 timing idealTree:node_modules/has-unicode Completed in 0ms
183 timing idealTree:node_modules/object-assign Completed in 0ms
184 silly placeDep ROOT string_decoder@1.3.0 OK for: readable-stream@3.6.2 want: ^1.1.1
185 silly placeDep ROOT util-deprecate@1.0.2 OK for: readable-stream@3.6.2 want: ^1.0.1
186 timing idealTree:node_modules/readable-stream Completed in 5ms
187 silly placeDep ROOT glob@7.2.3 OK for: rimraf@3.0.2 want: ^7.1.3
188 silly fetch manifest fs.realpath@^1.0.0
189 silly fetch manifest inflight@^1.0.4
190 silly fetch manifest minimatch@^3.1.1
191 silly fetch manifest once@^1.3.0
192 silly fetch manifest path-is-absolute@^1.0.0
193 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fs.realpath 36ms (cache hit)
194 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inflight 36ms (cache hit)
195 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch 35ms (cache hit)
196 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/once 36ms (cache hit)
197 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/path-is-absolute 30ms (cache hit)
198 timing idealTree:node_modules/rimraf Completed in 39ms
199 silly placeDep ROOT fs.realpath@1.0.0 OK for: glob@7.2.3 want: ^1.0.0
200 silly placeDep ROOT inflight@1.0.6 OK for: glob@7.2.3 want: ^1.0.4
201 silly fetch manifest wrappy@1
202 silly placeDep ROOT minimatch@3.1.2 OK for: glob@7.2.3 want: ^3.1.1
203 silly fetch manifest brace-expansion@^1.1.7
204 silly placeDep ROOT once@1.4.0 OK for: glob@7.2.3 want: ^1.3.0
205 silly placeDep ROOT path-is-absolute@1.0.1 OK for: glob@7.2.3 want: ^1.0.0
206 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/wrappy 8ms (cache hit)
207 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/brace-expansion 7ms (cache hit)
208 timing idealTree:node_modules/glob Completed in 15ms
209 timing idealTree:node_modules/fs.realpath Completed in 0ms
210 silly placeDep ROOT wrappy@1.0.2 OK for: inflight@1.0.6 want: 1
211 timing idealTree:node_modules/inflight Completed in 0ms
212 silly placeDep ROOT brace-expansion@1.1.11 OK for: minimatch@3.1.2 want: ^1.1.7
213 silly fetch manifest balanced-match@^1.0.0
214 silly fetch manifest concat-map@0.0.1
215 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/balanced-match 7ms (cache hit)
216 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/concat-map 7ms (cache hit)
217 timing idealTree:node_modules/minimatch Completed in 9ms
218 silly placeDep ROOT balanced-match@1.0.2 OK for: brace-expansion@1.1.11 want: ^1.0.0
219 silly placeDep ROOT concat-map@0.0.1 OK for: brace-expansion@1.1.11 want: 0.0.1
220 timing idealTree:node_modules/brace-expansion Completed in 2ms
221 timing idealTree:node_modules/balanced-match Completed in 0ms
222 timing idealTree:node_modules/concat-map Completed in 0ms
223 timing idealTree:node_modules/once Completed in 0ms
224 timing idealTree:node_modules/path-is-absolute Completed in 0ms
225 silly placeDep ROOT lru-cache@6.0.0 OK for: semver@7.5.4 want: ^6.0.0
226 timing idealTree:node_modules/semver Completed in 1ms
227 silly placeDep ROOT yallist@4.0.0 OK for: lru-cache@6.0.0 want: ^4.0.0
228 timing idealTree:node_modules/lru-cache Completed in 1ms
229 timing idealTree:node_modules/set-blocking Completed in 0ms
230 timing idealTree:node_modules/signal-exit Completed in 0ms
231 timing idealTree:node_modules/string_decoder Completed in 0ms
232 silly placeDep ROOT emoji-regex@8.0.0 OK for: string-width@4.2.3 want: ^8.0.0
233 silly placeDep ROOT is-fullwidth-code-point@3.0.0 OK for: string-width@4.2.3 want: ^3.0.0
234 timing idealTree:node_modules/string-width Completed in 3ms
235 timing idealTree:node_modules/emoji-regex Completed in 0ms
236 timing idealTree:node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point Completed in 0ms
237 silly placeDep ROOT ansi-regex@5.0.1 OK for: strip-ansi@6.0.1 want: ^5.0.1
238 timing idealTree:node_modules/strip-ansi Completed in 1ms
239 timing idealTree:node_modules/ansi-regex Completed in 0ms
240 silly placeDep ROOT chownr@2.0.0 OK for: tar@6.2.0 want: ^2.0.0
241 silly placeDep ROOT fs-minipass@2.1.0 OK for: tar@6.2.0 want: ^2.0.0
242 silly fetch manifest minipass@^3.0.0
243 silly placeDep ROOT minipass@5.0.0 OK for: tar@6.2.0 want: ^5.0.0
244 silly placeDep ROOT minizlib@2.1.2 OK for: tar@6.2.0 want: ^2.1.1
245 silly placeDep ROOT mkdirp@1.0.4 OK for: tar@6.2.0 want: ^1.0.3
246 timing idealTree:node_modules/tar Completed in 12ms
247 timing idealTree:node_modules/chownr Completed in 0ms
248 silly placeDep node_modules/fs-minipass minipass@3.3.6 OK for: fs-minipass@2.1.0 want: ^3.0.0
249 timing idealTree:node_modules/fs-minipass Completed in 1ms
250 timing idealTree:node_modules/minipass Completed in 0ms
251 silly placeDep node_modules/minizlib minipass@3.3.6 OK for: minizlib@2.1.2 want: ^3.0.0
252 timing idealTree:node_modules/minizlib Completed in 1ms
253 timing idealTree:node_modules/mkdirp Completed in 0ms
254 timing idealTree:node_modules/util-deprecate Completed in 0ms
255 silly placeDep ROOT tr46@0.0.3 OK for: whatwg-url@5.0.0 want: ~0.0.3
256 silly placeDep ROOT webidl-conversions@3.0.1 OK for: whatwg-url@5.0.0 want: ^3.0.0
257 timing idealTree:node_modules/whatwg-url Completed in 1ms
258 timing idealTree:node_modules/tr46 Completed in 0ms
259 timing idealTree:node_modules/webidl-conversions Completed in 0ms
260 timing idealTree:node_modules/wide-align Completed in 0ms
261 timing idealTree:node_modules/wrappy Completed in 0ms
262 timing idealTree:node_modules/yallist Completed in 0ms
263 silly placeDep node_modules/agent-base ms@2.1.2 OK for: debug@4.3.4 want: 2.1.2
264 timing idealTree:node_modules/agent-base/node_modules/debug Completed in 1ms
265 timing idealTree:node_modules/agent-base/node_modules/ms Completed in 0ms
266 timing idealTree:node_modules/fs-minipass/node_modules/minipass Completed in 0ms
267 silly placeDep node_modules/https-proxy-agent ms@2.1.2 OK for: debug@4.3.4 want: 2.1.2
268 timing idealTree:node_modules/https-proxy-agent/node_modules/debug Completed in 1ms
269 timing idealTree:node_modules/https-proxy-agent/node_modules/ms Completed in 0ms
270 timing idealTree:node_modules/make-dir/node_modules/semver Completed in 0ms
271 timing idealTree:node_modules/minizlib/node_modules/minipass Completed in 0ms
272 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 394ms
273 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
274 timing idealTree Completed in 436ms
275 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 437ms
276 timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 2ms
277 silly reify moves {}
278 timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
279 timing reify:createSparse Completed in 12ms
280 timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
281 silly audit bulk request {
281 silly audit   accepts: [ '1.3.8' ],
281 silly audit   'array-flatten': [ '1.1.1' ],
281 silly audit   'body-parser': [ '1.20.1' ],
281 silly audit   bytes: [ '3.1.2' ],
281 silly audit   'call-bind': [ '1.0.2' ],
281 silly audit   'content-disposition': [ '0.5.4' ],
281 silly audit   'content-type': [ '1.0.5' ],
281 silly audit   cookie: [ '0.5.0' ],
281 silly audit   'cookie-signature': [ '1.0.6' ],
281 silly audit   debug: [ '2.6.9', '4.3.4' ],
281 silly audit   depd: [ '2.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   destroy: [ '1.2.0' ],
281 silly audit   'ee-first': [ '1.1.1' ],
281 silly audit   encodeurl: [ '1.0.2' ],
281 silly audit   'escape-html': [ '1.0.3' ],
281 silly audit   etag: [ '1.8.1' ],
281 silly audit   express: [ '4.18.2' ],
281 silly audit   finalhandler: [ '1.2.0' ],
281 silly audit   forwarded: [ '0.2.0' ],
281 silly audit   fresh: [ '0.5.2' ],
281 silly audit   'function-bind': [ '1.1.1' ],
281 silly audit   'get-intrinsic': [ '1.2.1' ],
281 silly audit   has: [ '1.0.3' ],
281 silly audit   'has-proto': [ '1.0.1' ],
281 silly audit   'has-symbols': [ '1.0.3' ],
281 silly audit   'http-errors': [ '2.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   'iconv-lite': [ '0.4.24' ],
281 silly audit   inherits: [ '2.0.4' ],
281 silly audit   'ipaddr.js': [ '1.9.1' ],
281 silly audit   'media-typer': [ '0.3.0' ],
281 silly audit   'merge-descriptors': [ '1.0.1' ],
281 silly audit   methods: [ '1.1.2' ],
281 silly audit   mime: [ '1.6.0' ],
281 silly audit   'mime-db': [ '1.52.0' ],
281 silly audit   'mime-types': [ '2.1.35' ],
281 silly audit   ms: [ '2.0.0', '2.1.3', '2.1.2' ],
281 silly audit   negotiator: [ '0.6.3' ],
281 silly audit   'object-inspect': [ '1.12.3' ],
281 silly audit   'on-finished': [ '2.4.1' ],
281 silly audit   parseurl: [ '1.3.3' ],
281 silly audit   'path-to-regexp': [ '0.1.7' ],
281 silly audit   'proxy-addr': [ '2.0.7' ],
281 silly audit   qs: [ '6.11.0' ],
281 silly audit   'range-parser': [ '1.2.1' ],
281 silly audit   'raw-body': [ '2.5.1' ],
281 silly audit   'safe-buffer': [ '5.2.1' ],
281 silly audit   'safer-buffer': [ '2.1.2' ],
281 silly audit   send: [ '0.18.0' ],
281 silly audit   'serve-static': [ '1.15.0' ],
281 silly audit   setprototypeof: [ '1.2.0' ],
281 silly audit   'side-channel': [ '1.0.4' ],
281 silly audit   statuses: [ '2.0.1' ],
281 silly audit   toidentifier: [ '1.0.1' ],
281 silly audit   'type-is': [ '1.6.18' ],
281 silly audit   unpipe: [ '1.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   'utils-merge': [ '1.0.1' ],
281 silly audit   vary: [ '1.1.2' ],
281 silly audit   bcrypt: [ '5.1.1' ],
281 silly audit   '@mapbox/node-pre-gyp': [ '1.0.11' ],
281 silly audit   'node-addon-api': [ '5.1.0' ],
281 silly audit   'detect-libc': [ '2.0.2' ],
281 silly audit   'https-proxy-agent': [ '5.0.1' ],
281 silly audit   'make-dir': [ '3.1.0' ],
281 silly audit   'node-fetch': [ '2.7.0' ],
281 silly audit   nopt: [ '5.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   npmlog: [ '5.0.1' ],
281 silly audit   rimraf: [ '3.0.2' ],
281 silly audit   semver: [ '7.5.4', '6.3.1' ],
281 silly audit   tar: [ '6.2.0' ],
281 silly audit   'agent-base': [ '6.0.2' ],
281 silly audit   'whatwg-url': [ '5.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   abbrev: [ '1.1.1' ],
281 silly audit   'are-we-there-yet': [ '2.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   'console-control-strings': [ '1.1.0' ],
281 silly audit   gauge: [ '3.0.2' ],
281 silly audit   'set-blocking': [ '2.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   delegates: [ '1.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   'readable-stream': [ '3.6.2' ],
281 silly audit   aproba: [ '2.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   'color-support': [ '1.1.3' ],
281 silly audit   'has-unicode': [ '2.0.1' ],
281 silly audit   'object-assign': [ '4.1.1' ],
281 silly audit   'signal-exit': [ '3.0.7' ],
281 silly audit   'string-width': [ '4.2.3' ],
281 silly audit   'strip-ansi': [ '6.0.1' ],
281 silly audit   'wide-align': [ '1.1.5' ],
281 silly audit   string_decoder: [ '1.3.0' ],
281 silly audit   'util-deprecate': [ '1.0.2' ],
281 silly audit   glob: [ '7.2.3' ],
281 silly audit   'fs.realpath': [ '1.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   inflight: [ '1.0.6' ],
281 silly audit   minimatch: [ '3.1.2' ],
281 silly audit   once: [ '1.4.0' ],
281 silly audit   'path-is-absolute': [ '1.0.1' ],
281 silly audit   wrappy: [ '1.0.2' ],
281 silly audit   'brace-expansion': [ '1.1.11' ],
281 silly audit   'balanced-match': [ '1.0.2' ],
281 silly audit   'concat-map': [ '0.0.1' ],
281 silly audit   'lru-cache': [ '6.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   yallist: [ '4.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   'emoji-regex': [ '8.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   'is-fullwidth-code-point': [ '3.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   'ansi-regex': [ '5.0.1' ],
281 silly audit   chownr: [ '2.0.0' ],
281 silly audit   'fs-minipass': [ '2.1.0' ],
281 silly audit   minipass: [ '5.0.0', '3.3.6' ],
281 silly audit   minizlib: [ '2.1.2' ],
281 silly audit   mkdirp: [ '1.0.4' ],
281 silly audit   tr46: [ '0.0.3' ],
281 silly audit   'webidl-conversions': [ '3.0.1' ]
281 silly audit }
282 timing reifyNode:node_modules/detect-libc Completed in 195ms
283 timing reifyNode:node_modules/object-assign Completed in 214ms
284 timing reifyNode:node_modules/has-unicode Completed in 215ms
285 timing reifyNode:node_modules/set-blocking Completed in 213ms
286 timing reifyNode:node_modules/console-control-strings Completed in 213ms
287 timing reifyNode:node_modules/brace-expansion Completed in 219ms
288 timing reifyNode:node_modules/wrappy Completed in 219ms
289 timing reifyNode:node_modules/abbrev Completed in 215ms
290 timing reifyNode:node_modules/inflight Completed in 220ms
291 timing reifyNode:node_modules/wide-align Completed in 222ms
292 timing reifyNode:node_modules/string-width Completed in 222ms
293 timing reifyNode:node_modules/signal-exit Completed in 222ms
294 timing reifyNode:node_modules/aproba Completed in 217ms
295 timing reifyNode:node_modules/strip-ansi Completed in 222ms
296 timing reifyNode:node_modules/npmlog Completed in 218ms
297 timing reifyNode:node_modules/make-dir Completed in 218ms
298 timing reifyNode:node_modules/webidl-conversions Completed in 223ms
299 timing reifyNode:node_modules/color-support Completed in 223ms
300 timing reifyNode:node_modules/path-is-absolute Completed in 224ms
301 timing reifyNode:node_modules/once Completed in 224ms
302 timing reifyNode:node_modules/lru-cache Completed in 224ms
303 timing reifyNode:node_modules/yallist Completed in 226ms
304 timing reifyNode:node_modules/balanced-match Completed in 226ms
305 timing reifyNode:node_modules/fs.realpath Completed in 227ms
306 timing reifyNode:node_modules/util-deprecate Completed in 227ms
307 timing reifyNode:node_modules/string_decoder Completed in 227ms
308 timing reifyNode:node_modules/chownr Completed in 227ms
309 timing reifyNode:node_modules/agent-base/node_modules/ms Completed in 222ms
310 timing reifyNode:node_modules/minizlib/node_modules/minipass Completed in 230ms
311 timing reifyNode:node_modules/fs-minipass/node_modules/minipass Completed in 230ms
312 timing reifyNode:node_modules/https-proxy-agent/node_modules/ms Completed in 227ms
313 timing reifyNode:node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point Completed in 232ms
314 timing reifyNode:node_modules/minimatch Completed in 232ms
315 timing reifyNode:node_modules/fs-minipass Completed in 232ms
316 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ansi-regex Completed in 232ms
317 timing reifyNode:node_modules/rimraf Completed in 229ms
318 timing reifyNode:node_modules/minizlib Completed in 234ms
319 timing reifyNode:node_modules/concat-map Completed in 239ms
320 timing reifyNode:node_modules/delegates Completed in 234ms
321 timing reifyNode:node_modules/are-we-there-yet Completed in 234ms
322 timing reifyNode:node_modules/tr46 Completed in 240ms
323 timing reifyNode:node_modules/nopt Completed in 237ms
324 timing reifyNode:node_modules/mkdirp Completed in 242ms
325 timing reifyNode:node_modules/minipass Completed in 242ms
326 timing reifyNode:node_modules/agent-base/node_modules/debug Completed in 237ms
327 timing reifyNode:node_modules/glob Completed in 242ms
328 timing reifyNode:node_modules/https-proxy-agent/node_modules/debug Completed in 238ms
329 timing reifyNode:node_modules/whatwg-url Completed in 241ms
330 timing reifyNode:node_modules/emoji-regex Completed in 246ms
331 timing reifyNode:node_modules/make-dir/node_modules/semver Completed in 242ms
332 timing reifyNode:node_modules/https-proxy-agent Completed in 244ms
333 timing reifyNode:node_modules/agent-base Completed in 245ms
334 timing reifyNode:node_modules/node-fetch Completed in 250ms
335 timing reifyNode:node_modules/gauge Completed in 250ms
336 timing reifyNode:node_modules/tar Completed in 262ms
337 timing reifyNode:node_modules/readable-stream Completed in 263ms
338 timing reifyNode:node_modules/bcrypt Completed in 265ms
339 timing reifyNode:node_modules/node-addon-api Completed in 266ms
340 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp Completed in 269ms
341 timing reifyNode:node_modules/semver Completed in 271ms
342 timing reify:unpack Completed in 276ms
343 timing reify:unretire Completed in 0ms
344 timing build:queue Completed in 6ms
345 timing build:link:node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp Completed in 1ms
346 timing build:link:node_modules/color-support Completed in 0ms
347 timing build:link:node_modules/mkdirp Completed in 0ms
348 timing build:link:node_modules/nopt Completed in 0ms
349 timing build:link:node_modules/rimraf Completed in 0ms
350 timing build:link:node_modules/semver Completed in 0ms
351 timing build:link:node_modules/make-dir/node_modules/semver Completed in 1ms
352 timing build:link Completed in 2ms
353 info run bcrypt@5.1.1 install node_modules/bcrypt node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
354 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 360ms
355 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 364ms
356 silly audit report {}
357 timing auditReport:init Completed in 0ms
358 timing reify:audit Completed in 364ms
359 info run bcrypt@5.1.1 install { code: 7, signal: null }
360 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 46ms
361 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
362 timing command:install Completed in 997ms
363 verbose stack Error: command failed
363 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:53:27)
363 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
363 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
363 verbose stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:303:5)
364 verbose pkgid bcrypt@5.1.1
365 verbose cwd /home/roee/Projects/Xxx/Xxx-Systems-Website
366 verbose Linux 6.2.0-33-generic
367 verbose node v18.18.0
368 verbose npm  v10.1.0
369 error code 7
370 error path /home/roee/Projects/Xxx/Xxx-Systems-Website/node_modules/bcrypt
371 error command failed
372 error command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
373 verbose exit 7
374 timing npm Completed in 1138ms
375 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1695594846727
376 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1695594847467
377 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1695594847467
378 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1695594847467
379 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install 1695594847475
380 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/bcrypt 1695594847475
381 verbose code 7
382 error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/roee/.npm/_logs/2023-09-24T22_34_06_584Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps.

1. clear npm cache `sudo npm cache clean -f`
2. install stable version of npm `sudo npm install -g n`
3. then `sudo n stable`
4. finally `npm i bcrypt`

credit from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXm4V794kiw

If you follow the above steps and still no joy, make sure you have the required dependencies installed in your system.

According to bcrypt docs. You will need to install `gcc` `python` and `make`. by running this command.

`sudo apt-get install -y build-essential python`

However, you most likely face an error while the command try to install python so you might want to install python directly by install `python2`(according to bcrypt only version is supported).

Ref - `https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions#ubuntu-and-derivatives---elementary-linux-mint-etc`